# Getting nth row on mssql - What that "sq" mean?

Tags: sql-server, pymssql

Need to get nth row from a table. i found this query, which works exactly matching the requirement.

```
SELECT TOP 1 name FROM (SELECT TOP 9 name FROM master..syslogins ORDER BY name ASC) sq ORDER BY name DESC
```

Not sure what is the "sq" in the query point to, so that i can customize for my requirement.

Can anyone let me know what is the "sq" in the above query points to??

### Tried:

```
SELECT TOP 1 user FROM (SELECT TOP 3 user FROM customers ORDER BY user ASC)sq ORDER BY   user DESC
```

Issue error: No column name was specified for column 1 of 'sq'

Comment: It is an alias for the subquery.

Comment: i also thought the same.But when i customize the query with different table name "sq" is issuing an error as invalid column name

Comment: @seanlange i have added the customized query and error. pls check it..

Comment: `user` is a keyword in T-SQL. You need to escape it -- `[user]` -- or the parser gets confused.

Comment: @JeroenMostert oh bad. Silly mistake. Thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use : [] for column names that match with keywords

```
SELECT TOP 1 [user] FROM (SELECT TOP 3 [user] FROM customers ORDER BY user ASC)sq ORDER BY  [user] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

"sq" in your case is the alias for the inline view. An standard use of alias is preceded by keyword "as" (so in your case that would translate in " as sq ". The alias is the new name of the query and must be separated by the query by at least one blank space.